# Using rate-limits when working with web-hooks

Tags: github, github-api, github-api-v3

Our company has a monitoring service for github repositories working using the web-hooks. Does their usage consume rate-limits?

Comment: No. Rate limits are for API usage. Does your company use the API?

Comment: Yes, also we have a github client using API v3. Can you send a link confirming your words?

Comment: A request *to* GitHub via API is usually subject to rate limits https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting. A webhook is *from* GitHub so doesn't have rate limits.